# how to specify printconfiguration with Android plug-in for Gradle v1.5.0?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

With Android plug-in for Gradle v1.3.1, we can specify printconfiguration option for Proguard as below:

```
variant.obfuscation.doFirst {
  def cfg_file = new File(mappingFile.parent, "config.txt")
  printconfiguration cfg_file
}
```

It does not work with Android plug-in for Gradle v1.5.0
How do I specify printconfiguration option with v1.5.0?﻿

Comment: @rekire I am talking about "Android Plugin for Gradle", not "Gradle". The latest official release of "Android Plugin for Gradle" is v1.5.0